# Dual citizen entering EU with foreign passport

Tags: schengen, france, dual-nationality, 90-180-visa-rules

I'm a Canadian citizen, and I have a girlfriend (and the start of a new life) waiting for me in France. I have returned to Canada to acquire my Portuguese nationality and am awaiting the documentation asserting that I am now a Portuguese citizen. With this, I will be able to live and work in France until I am ready to marry.

- I visited France at the beginning of July 2014.
- I stayed for a total of 80 days of the 90/180 Schengen rule.
- After I receive my Portuguese citizenship, I will have to wait for another 1.5 months before receiving my identity card and Portuguese passport.

I have already been away from my girlfriend and "life" more than I'd care to be, and it's also financially draining.

- Once I receive the documentation stating that I am a Portuguese citizen, can I return to France on my Canadian passport?
- Would the 90/180 rule apply to me since I entered on the Canadian passport?
- If I entered on my Canadian passport, would I have to leave on it the next time I fly out of Europe?

  - If I did, would it count as overstaying?

I'm not worried about getting the citizen card or passport, because I could apply for those at the Portuguese Embassy in France.

Comment: I am a bit confused: Will you become a Portuguese citizen or merely have your citizenship (e.g. by descent) recognized? Also what type of documentation will you get? Shouldn't you get a [Portuguese national ID card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Card_(Portugal))?

Comment: As R says, your question is confusing.  Just FWIW: (1) "Once I receive the documentation stating that I am a Portuguese citizen, can I return to France on my Canadian passport?"  sure, nobody cares at the border. it's not like they are going to "look up" that you also have some portugese paper. read the many many questions on here about various dual-passport situations. (2) "If I entered on my Canadian passport, would I have to leave on it the next time I fly out of Europe?" not particularly. "If I did, would it count as overstaying?" i think you'd basically say "look I'm an EU citizen now"

Comment: Let me clarify:after becoming a Portuguese citizen, I would enter the EU solely on my Canadian passport. Then, I would get my Portuguese national ID card and Portuguese passport in Paris. What I'm worried about is this: since I technically entered as a Canadian, but I am an EU citizen, would I be booked for overstaying?

Answer (score 7):

The thing that's illegal is to *be present within Schengen without being entitled to*. Passports and entry/exit stamps are merely a means of *detecting* if you're guilty of that -- but ultimately what counts is what *you* do, not what your passport does.

Once you're a Portuguese citizen you *inherently* have a right to be present within the Schengen area, and therefore you cannot possibly be guilty of overstaying.

Your Canadian passport with only an entry stamp will *look like* it belongs to someone who has overstayed -- but you haven't actually. Once you prove your new citizenship it will be clear that you're not doing anything wrong, no matter that the usual procedure for finding out whether a passport looks suspect or not fails in your case.

You would have to provide a longer-than-usual explanation if you try to use the Canadian passport as a travel document at the Schengen borders after it has begun to look as if it is overstayed, but no actual guilt ought to attach to you.

Comment: I agree with you completely. The EU regulation concerning the right of free movement for EU citizens especially specifies, that a passport or national id card is *not* required, but that EU citizens can prove their rights with "any means". Even if it might cause some hassle at the border or during an internal control, a Canadian passport and a Portuguese citizenship certificate should be more than enough.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That's another important detail (albeit possibly difficult to use in practice) but I think Henning's point was slightly different. Even if you do not have any proof whatsoever of your citizenship and do not make any attempt to establish it *when entering the country*, you are still an EU citizen and cannot be fined for overstaying later on.

Comment: @Relaxed: Sure. My point is perhaps not quite relevant, as long as you have a non-EU passport, allowing you to enter the EU in the first place. French immigration is unlikely to have any records of the previous 80 days stay, so having only 10 days "left" of the 90 days allowed is also not going to cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit France, or any other country in the Schengen zone, on your Canadian passport; if you enter as a Canadian and present only a Canadian passport, visitor rules will apply even if you hold citizenship of a member state. So yes, the 90 day restriction and cooling off period would apply.

For your last question, you do not have to go through non-EU exit controls if you have an EU passport, and you will not be booked for overstaying. However, it's a good idea to clear the zone on your Canadian passport rather than to have a 'glitch', however innocuous, in the computer.

**Adding 19 Feb 2015 as a result of commentary**

It is a fallacy to assume that the evidence used to successfully apply for Portuguese citizenship is fungible in an EU-wide context.  Bestowing Portuguese citizenship is a matter arising solely under Portuguese national law and there is no reason to believe that that ancient birth records, marriage records, DNA tests and the like would be acceptable to a French border official.

They will want to see something understandable and acceptable within the EU framework.  It does not necessarily have to be a passport or national ID card, but it would have to be something with a widely known (or widely recognized) counterpart in the other EU members.

And of course it goes without saying that when you are able to establish your EU nationality in an acceptable way that you can then benefit from the Free Movement Directive.

Comment: (+1) I am not sure that there would in fact be a record of the entry.

Comment: @carluge, no need for thanks, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Relaxed, it's quite likely there would be an entry in the DHS system if the op left from Canada.

Comment: How about if I entered France using rail from the UK? I heard they check passport on the train, but they don't necessarily log it in or sometimes even stamp.

Comment: @GayotFow Probably, I was speaking about the French side of things.

Comment: @carluge They are *supposed* to stamp all the same and they actually check at the station, before boarding the train. But I don't think France logs anything, even when coming in by plane.

Comment: @Relaxed If they don't log anything, then I'm set to go because I could always leave in my portuguese passport. Anything online about this sort of thing?

Comment: @carluge Unfortunately, I have never been able to definitely confirm that. But, like Gayot and other said, I don't think it matters in your case.

Comment: Overstaying is one of several consequences, the OP has limited his vision to that one only, and the rest are out of scope for this question.

Comment: @gayot what other consequences or worries do you feel I should be concerned with?

Comment: -1.  This is incorrect.  If you can show that you are Portuguese, you can stay in France for as long as you want provided you meet the criteria for exercising your "treaty rights" -- for example, by being employed.  It doesn't matter how you got there.

Comment: @phoog, he cannot show that he is Portuguese without a Portuguese passport, hence unable to show that he's Portuguese, hence unable to exercise treaty rights. Did you actually read the question?

Comment: @GayotFow the first statement is incorrect.  He must in fact show that he is Portuguese in order to apply for the Portuguese passport.  Whatever evidence he used for the application (a letter from a consulate, for example, confirming Portuguese nationality) would also serve as evidence of Portuguese nationality when in France.  Did *you* read the question?  Part of it asks "once I receive the documentation confirming my Portuguese nationality..."

Comment: @phoog, answer amended to clarify. You have already voted and explained your position and well done for that.  Time to move on...

Comment: No! I need to convince you! (tongue/cheek) Seriously, what I meant was this: to get the passport, OP probably had to submit an official signed sealed letter from the govt. confirming that OP is Portuguese. Birth records and the like were used to obtain that letter. That's how it worked for me in a different EU country. Granted, French authorities might refuse to accept an official letter as proof of nationality because of the possibility of forgery, but I doubt they would. I agree that they wouldn't accept birth records etc. because that would require them to interpret Portuguese law.